# Understanding of Terms in The Theorem of Sums and Direct Sums

Tags: linear-algebra

*Theorem*. Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $K$, and let $U$, $W$ be subspaces. If $U+W=V$, and if $U \cap W$={$0$}, then $V$ is the direct sum of $U$ and $W$.

My question is that what is '$U \cap W$={$0$}' mean? Can you explain detailed?

Comment: It's a typo : it should be $W$ and not $B$.

Comment: I means that $x\in U\cap W$ implies that $x=0$.

Comment: @CaptainLama It cannot be typo. Can you see **Answer**?

Comment: It is a typo, and I don't really know why the answer doesn't mention it. But you can see that the answer discusses $U\cap W$ and not $U\cap B$.

Comment: I thought it was a typo as well. I didn't refer to it, because I thought Captain's comment clarified that already.

Comment: @CaptainLama Sorry. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$U\cap W=\{0\}$ reads as "the intersection of $U$ and $W$ is the set containing only the zero element."

In other words, the two spaces only share the zero vector. They do not share any other vectors and are (almost) disjoint. We define the direct sum $U+W= V$ as a vector space that includes all the vectors in $U$ and all the vectors in $W$, specifically under the circumstance that $U\cap W=\{0\}$.